# Difficult limit with "nested expectations"

Tags: limits, proof-verification

$Y$ and $Z$ are non-negative random variables with $E(Y)=E(Z)=1$, finite second moments, and $0<Corr(Y,Z)<1$. Both variables may be assumed to have a bounded support if necessary. As part of a proof of existence of a solution for a nonlinear equation, I am trying to compute  $$\lim_{a\to \infty} E((Y - 1) (\frac{Y^a}{E(Y^a)} - Z)). $$

I believe this limit should be positive, but I am struggling to prove this is the case (or to disprove it).

Any comments or suggestions would be really appreciated.